# Measuring textsize depending on style

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i need to measure the string width and height depending on some style attributes like font, fontsize and fontattributes (bold/italic). How can i do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Android, it provide the `getTextBounds` to retrieve the text boundary box and store to bounds. Return in bounds.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#getTextBounds(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect)

In Xamarin.Forms, we could use Dependency Service to do that.

```
 public interface CalculateTextWidth
{
    double calculateWidth(string text);
}
```

Android Implementation:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CalculateTextWidth_Android))]
namespace App6.Droid
{
public class CalculateTextWidth_Android : CalculateTextWidth
{
    public double calculateWidth(string text)
    {
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        TextView textView = new TextView(Forms.Context);
        textView.Paint.GetTextBounds(text, 0, text.Length, bounds);
        var length = bounds.Width();
        return length / Resources.System.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity;
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

```
   private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = DependencyService.Get<CalculateTextWidth>().calculateWidth(label.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I now use SkiaSharps MeasureText Method.